# Using UIWebView to call the Upload method

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, amazon-s3

I want to upload some data to Amazon S3. I must use the UIWebView call from the Amazon SDK (multipartUpload:) to achieve that.

The main problem is that my `ViewController` freezes execution until the upload finishes.

Is there a way to solve this? I tried starting a new thread from WebView for just the upload Upload method, but the application crashes.

And the second question: Does anyone know of any functions that would allow pausing/resuming uploads in Amazon S3?

Comment: why does the uiwebview have to manage the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the upload on a background thread.

```
    // perform edit asynchronously to avoid blocking ui
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
             //UPLOAD CODE GOES HERE AND RUNS OUTSIDE OF THE MAINTHREAD SO NO UI IS BLOCKED
    });
```

Here is a link that goes into using grand central dispatch to perform async processes.

http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/

Comment: As I wrote it caused crash. Thread 11:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x10)

Comment: A bad access error would be caused by something that is referenced after it has been released. I log to see if your upload attribute hasn't been released in the async block.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputat. Sorry, I can't do it now, but I'll do it later